# I want to add JOBID with the query

Tags: sql

I want to return the efficiency with respect to JOBID but when it make changes to the below query to check it in mysql workbench it doesn't work. The desired query doesn't work.

Actual Query:

```
select 'Efficiency' Field, avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) 
from (
    select (Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff 
    from ras
)as s;
```

Desired Query:

```
select JobID 
from (
  select 'Efficiency' Field,avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) as f 
  from (
     select (Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff 
     from ras
  )
) as s;
```

Comment: Where does `jobid` come from?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you need a table alias for the derived table:

```
select JobID 
from (select 'Efficiency' as Field, avg(eff), min(eff), max(eff) as f 
      from (select (Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff 
            from ras
           ) s
    ) s;
```

You also need a column alias called `JobID` if you want to select that.

Conceivably, you might just want to aggregate by `JobId`:

```
select JobId, 'Efficiency' as Field, avg(eff), min(eff), max(eff) as f 
from (select ras.*, (Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff 
      from ras
     ) s
group by JobId;
```

Comment: How to eliminate null values from it?

Comment: i want to work this condition in this query   :                     WHERE LC_Final,LC_Preview,Job_Render IS NOT NULL